# Why are Xamarin debug builds so big, and how can I reduce the size?

Tags: debugging, xamarin

A simple "Hello World" program built with Debug mode in Xamarin has a size of 50mb without even including the installed Monoruntime and other things such as that.

While I'm guessing that release builds are smaller, I would also like to reduce the size of the debug builds, without losing any debug functionality, so that I rebuild my apps faster.

So, why are Xamarin debug builds so large and how can I reduce the size of them without sacrificing debug functionality?

Comment: I would ask: Why does it matter what the debug size of the build is? You can enable `Linking` which you normally would do just for release packaging, at the cost of build times, but this defeats using the debug shared runtime to enable faster build/deploy/debug cycles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Project Build Options, enable Linking.  By default it is turned off in Debug to improve build times.

More detail here: [Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/) and [iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/)

Comment: How does enabling linking decrease debug build times, afterall doesn't it reduce the size of the final app?

Comment: Enabling linking INCREASES build times.  That's why it's disabled by default for debug builds.

Answer (score 0):

**Xamarin.Android**

We have a guide here which goes into detail about Xamarin.Android app sizes:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/application_package_sizes/

**Xamarin.iOS**

Xamarin app sizes are slightly bigger than Objective-C apps as the Mono framework is part of the app bundle.

The architectures you build for will also increase the app size as a binary will be created for each one - I suggest that you only build for ARMv7 and ARM64, omitting ARMv7s unless you need to utilise the specific optimisations provided with that architecture.

You can potentially reduce the app size by setting the linker options to link all assemblies in your release configuration:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/linker/#Link_all_assemblies

Each nuget package added to your project will also increase the size of your app. However, with the use of the linker, the impact of this will depend on how much of the package you are actually using. Anything unused will be stripped out during the linking process.

For a unified app (supports multiple architectures), Apple is considering each architecture separately for the download size limitations of the App Store. So if your deliverable came in at 100mb (for the sake of example, 50mb per architecture), Apple would see it as a 50mb download and not the overall 100mb.

You can also reduce your app size by looking at what other assets you have included in your app, such as images, and see if you can save space by making them smaller or increasing compression.

As a final note, the App Store adds it's own encryption to your app which can significantly increase the overall size. As encrpytion obfuscates patterns, the resuting compressed app will be larger. The impact varies from app to app. Moving data, such as long strings, or tables, out of code and into external files will make the final download smaller, because those files will be compressed more efficiently.